# how do you stop a variable from being Serialized?

Tags: android, serialization

EG

```
public class SomeObject implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5394297791806714290L;

private long m_id;
private String m_name;
private String m_blah;
}
```

How would you stop m_blah from being serialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `transient` keyword on `m_blah`